# Pocketsphinx import ValueError

Tags: python, osx-lion, cmusphinx

I recently installed pocketsphinx modules on my mac running Lion and Python 2.7.3(Not Apple's built in python, but brewed). I tried to run the following code:

```
import pocketsphinx as p
decoder = p.Decoder(jsgf='/path_to_jsgf_file/grammar.jsgf',samprate='8000')
fh = open('myrecording.wav', 'rb')
nsamp = decoder.decode_raw(fh)
print 'You said,', hyp
print 'Your score was', score
```

But here's the error I get on running `import pocketsphinx as p :`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "speech_reco.py", line 4, in <module>
import pocketsphinx as p
File "sphinxbase.pxd", line 150, in init pocketsphinx (pocketsphinx.c:7935)
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with invalid PyCapsule object
```

However, it runs correctly when the import command is run the second time. Therefore, presently, I'm running a try-catch there and getting past the error. But I don't know whether this still works.

This issue seems to have come up before,as discussed on this link: http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/bugs/284/

Has anyone fixed this issue yet? If not, would try- catch be the right way to get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anyone fixed this issue yet? If not, would try- catch be the right way to get around this error?

This Cython issue is fixed in later Cython

> If not, would try- catch be the right way to get around this error?

The right way to get around this error is to recreate glue code with Cython. The last message in the bug report says that:

http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/bugs/284/

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I have been trying to follow that approach, but I am really unable to find the .c files that the last comment talks about.
This is where all the files for pocketsphinx and sphinxbase are located ```/usr/local/Cellar/``` but I was unable to find sphinxbase.c and pocketsphinx.c. I'm really sorry if my question is too basic, but I've never used this sort of a technique before.

Comment: Those files are in python subfolders of both sphinxbase and pocketsphinx.

Comment: I think I've done something wrong during installation of python, maybe, because I'm unable to find the files anywhere in the python subfolders. I'm probably searching wrongly. I searched in the subfolders of the ```python``` folder in the ```usr/local/Cellar/``` but am unable to locate these files.
There are ```pocketsphinx.pc`` and ```pocketsphinx.h``` files in the previously mentioned pocketsphinx directory in the Cellar folder.

Comment: So, does installing via homebrew cause the issue? Because, it doesn't look like all the components of the pocketsphinx and sphinxbase modules are present. However ```import command``` seems to work fine. So, I tried running ```python -v``` to see what happens and where the modules are being imported from. Here was the result: ```dlopen("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx.so", 2);
dlopen("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase.so", 2);
import sphinxbase # dynamically loaded from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinxbase.so
```

Comment: What does the ```dynamic loading``` part mean? Does this mean my modules were not installed correctly?

Comment: > So, does installing via homebrew cause the issue

No

> What does the dynamic loading part mean? Does this mean my modules were not installed correctly?

It means modules were installed correctly

Comment: Ah, but I still can't find the .c files, although the I did find the .so files. I'm really sorry, but could you elaborate slightly on how I can access the source files and reach the .c files?

Comment: Probably you need to read more about homebrew and how it builds from sources.

Comment: I understand, I've been up to the task since yesterday. 
But to just close this thread, will repeating the ```import pocketsphinx``` statement cause trouble in terms of accuracy of answer?

Comment: CMUSphinx has moved from Cython to SWIG recently, so this issue is not relevant anymore, you can just checkout latest sphinxbase/pocketsphinx from subversion and build them with Python support.